# simple title fo rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i want in my app do next: 
if i do not set my title by my self - title show "App" 
if i set title -> <%= title "Welcome" %> title show "Welcome"

i do: index.html.erb

```
<%= title "Welcome controller" %>
```

applicaton.html.erb:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title><%= yield(:title) %></title>
```

Application helper:

```
module ApplicationHelper
def title(page_title)
  content_for(:title) { page_title  }
end  
end
```

i want something like that:

```
 <title><%= yield(:title) || "App" %></title>
```

but that's not work - why ? (display -> htp://local.... )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`yield(:title)` won't return false, or null.  If you wanted it to work similar to how you have it you might use `content_for?` which would return false if nothing had been defined:

```
<%= content_for?(:title) ? yield(:title) : 'App' %>
```

But if your `title` setter is just a proxy to `content_for`, why not make a helper for the getter as well?  I've seen patterns like this often, where the same `title` method is used to both get and set the title.  This is a very simple example but you get the idea:

```
# your helper
def title(val)
  @_title = val || @_title || "App"      
end

# some template
<% title "Welcome" %>

# some layout
<title><%= title %></title>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could change your helper:

```
content_for(:title) { page_title || "App" }
```

However, I'm curious as to why you don't set a title variable in your controller and just use that?